# Relationship of Summation and Integration!

Tags: calculus, integration, power-series

I wanted to check the difference between summing over a function vs integrating over the function in a given interval $[0, N]$.
Here's the [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/3owkacefsr) file which you can also play with the function and parameters.
The function is as follows:
$$
f(x) = j H(x) e^{-x/\tau}
$$
$H(x)$ is the Heaviside function.
Then taking the integral would give us:
$$
\int_0^N f(x)dx = \tau j (e^{-N/\tau} - 1)
$$
I noticed that there's a linear relationship between the integral and the sum of the function.
$$
D = \frac{\int_0^N f(x)dx}{\sum_{n=1}^N f(n)}
$$
Which is invariant to the value of $N$.

Firstly, In desmos $D = 1.092$. Is this $D$ coming from the equality below so $D=\Delta x$?
$$
\sum f(n) \Delta x = \int f(x)dx
$$
And secondly, how can someone write the sum of such a function based on the solution of its integral?

Comment: I wouldn't look for a deep explanation here. The Heaviside function simply restricts the interval of integration/indices of summation to smaller intervals. Then the integral is elementary to evaluate, and the sum is also elementary because it's a geometric series. That the answers are so similar is a special property of exponential functions/geometric series.

Comment: If you're more generally interested in the relationship between sums and integrals of the same function, see the [Euler-Maclaurin formula](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Euler-MaclaurinIntegrationFormulas.html).